# mysql table problem?

Tags: mysql

i have these two tables tables for a chatting app

```
users{user_id,username,pictures}
chat_data(con_id, chat_text}
```

i used this sql query

```
SELECT c.chat_text, u.username
FROM chat_data c, users u
WHERE c.con_id =1
```

but its giving me duplicate results, when i know thiers only row with the con_id =1, what is the problem with the query!! :))

Comment: can u display some table contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to "join" the tables to avoid duplicates. For example

```
SELECT c.chat_text, u.username
FROM chat_data c, users u
WHERE c.con_id =1
  and u.id = c.user_id
```

You can read a bit about [relational algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra) which is the theory behind relational databases.

Answer (score 1):

The `users` and `chat_data` tables should be JOINED in order to get a unique tuple as result.
Since `users` and `chat_data` cannot be joined, you simply get **Cartesian product** of the two tables.

> **Cartesian Products**
>
> If two tables in a join query have no
>   join condition, then Oracle Database
>   returns their Cartesian product.
>   Oracle combines each row of one table
>   with each row of the other. A
>   Cartesian product always generates
>   many rows and is rarely useful. For
>   example, the Cartesian product of two
>   tables, each with 100 rows, has 10,000
>   rows. Always include a join condition
>   unless you specifically need a
>   Cartesian product. If a query joins
>   three or more tables and you do not
>   specify a join condition for a
>   specific pair, then the optimizer may
>   choose a join order that avoids
>   producing an intermediate Cartesian
>   product.

Refer: http://www.stanford.edu/dept/itss/docs/oracle/10g/server.101/b10759/queries006.htm

Answer (score 0):

With a query like that, you will get as many rows in the results as there are rows in the table users.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the type of join the SQL is doing. Is it returning a row for each user you have? This is what I expect it is doing, i.e. if you have 2 users John and Jack then are you getting a row for both of these users being returned?

Are you just trying to get the data related to the users involved in a conversation? If so you need some link between the 2 tables, like foreign key references from the chat_data table referencing users.

Answer (score 0):

As previously stated, you're missing a link between the two tables. If you are trying to retrieve the user associated to a particular chat you will need to add a foreign key reference in chat_data that references user.user_id. But if you are trying to get multiple users associated to a chat you would need to add a new table. Your new tables would look something like this:

users{user_id,username,pictures}
chat_data(con_id, chat_text}
user_chat(user_id, con_id) //By adding this new table you can have multiple users per chat

The the query would look something like

SELECT u.username, c.chat_text
FROM users u, chat_data c, user_chat uc
WHERE u.id = uc.id
AND c.con_id = uc.con_id